Do there exist infinitely many integers that fit the following condition?
Q: Do there exist infinitely many integers $a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_n,\cdots$, $a_0\neq0$, such that for any $n\ge1$, the polynomial $p_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k$ always has $n$ distinct real roots?
It is not hard to find that, if $p_n(x)$ has $n$ distinct real roots, then $p_n'(x)$ has $n-1$ distinct real roots, which implies that if $\{a_k\}$ fits the condition, then $\{ka_k\}$ also fits the condition. So WLOG, we can assume that $\{|a_k|\}$ is increasing. I guess we can use this assumption to solve the problem (because we can restrict all the roots into a specific interval). At the same time, the discreteness is also an important method (because the real number version is apparent).

What does "the real number version is apparent" mean?

Guess it means that the related problem with real-valued $a_k$ is obviously solvable in the positive. Indeed, when you have $p_n(x)$ with the desired property, you may add the next term with $a_{n+1}$ so small as not to disturb the existing roots, while adding the new root far away where $x^{n+1}$ dominates over the rest.

See Marty's solution here, $ \sum x^n / n!$ works.

@CalvinLin The question asks for integers $a_k$.

What is the justification for assuming that $|a_k|$ is increasing? It's not true if the $a_k$ are real numbers instead of integers.

It's because the statement is belived to be false. The assumption is used to conclude a contradiction.

For $n$ fixed, let $r_1, \ldots, r_n$ be the $n$ nonzero real roots of $p_n(x)$. Then by the AM-GM inequality,
$$ \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{r_1^2}+ \ldots + \frac{1}{r_n^2}\right)  \ge \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{(r_1\cdots r_n)^2}}.$$
Using Vieta's formulas, this becomes
$$ \frac{1}{n}\left(\left(\frac{a_1}{a_0}\right)^2 - 2\frac{a_2}{a_0}\right) \ge \sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{a_n}{a_0}\right)^2} \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{a_0^2}}.$$
As $n$ goes to infinity, the left-hand side goes to $0$ while the right-hand side goes to $1$, so there is an $n$ (that we could explicitly compute from $a_0, a_1$, and $a_2$ if we wanted to) beyond which this inequality fails (and therefore all further $p_n(x)$ have at least one pair of complex roots).
